# How to replace YUIDoc's index partial with the classes partial?

Tags: javascript, node.js, yui, yuidoc

I'm trying to build docs from source on one of my plugins. Everything works fine now but the index page is empty and useless. I want to replace the index partial with the content of the classes partial since that's the only useful info for this plugin.

It looks like the index partial doesn't have access to the data that's available in the classes partial?

I've attached two screenshots to illustrate what I'm talking about. The second screen shot is what I want to show on the index page. I've tried importing the partial there but nothing rendered except for a static heading.

[image: Index page]
[image: Classes page]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not able to do it easy because the index template of theme doesn't have all classes and modules data.

Please feel free to file an issue on GitHub, or patch welcome.

Comment: I ended up using gulp to replace the `index.html` with the content of the classes file. Works out fine :) http://dropkickjs.com